# Getting time of tweet

Tags: api, twitter4j

I want to use twitter data for temporal database, but I need the time that the tweet was created.

CreatedAt() only giving the details of account creation date.

Is there any API for getting tweet's time?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at `created_at`. See [the twitter dev page](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets):

> **created_at**
>
> String
>   UTC time when this Tweet was created.
>
> Example:
>
> `"created_at":"Wed Aug 27 13:08:45 +0000 2008"`

Comment: created_at String UTC time when this Tweet was created.
Example:

"created_at":"Wed Aug 27 13:08:45 +0000 2008"

Comment: There is, its the third one down

Comment: this shows the creation time of that particular account not tweet

Comment: It shows the account creation date if you are asking on the user, if you ask on the tweet you will get the date that you want